# Why do I have different nodes on the shader editor than this tutorial?

Tags: node-editor, vector-mapping

Specifically the mapping node. Trying to plug a value into the scale and mine doesn’t let me[image: here is his]

[image: and this is mine]

Comment: What version of blender are you using?

Comment: [How to take a ScreenShot](https://www.take-a-screenshot.org/windows.html)

Comment: Looks like I have blender 2.80. I’ll try and download 2.83 when I get back home where I have fast WiFi and see if that solves it.

Comment: And yeah I know how to take a screenshot I’m posting from my iPad because I have slow internet at the moment and it works better on here than on my pc

Comment: on the first screenshot it is the new Mapping node, if you want to use it as it is used on the second screenshot, you just need to plug the Texture Coordinate into the top socket as it is already correctly done